# Modal jQuery dialog hidden behind overlay in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am developing some Jquery dialog and found the dialog was hidden when I set Modal: true. When setting Modal: false, I found everything works as expected. Hope someone can help me.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOpendialog" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<div id="dialog">

<h1>Test</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClickfromDialog" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</div>

$(function () {
    $("#btnOpendialog").click(function (e) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        height: 200,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function () {
            $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        }                              
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed it. There aren't many people who're complaining about this issue. Is it just me? Anyway, here is how I fixed it. Quite simple when you know how.

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
        z-index: 0;   
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Worked for me, although I had to use !Important to make sure it took precedence.

Comment: for other people coming to this page, as @Eddie R mentioned, you should use the new API `$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" });`

Answer (score 12):

I tried the accepted answer and it appeared to work in some situations, but not others. Using the same idea, this is the code I came up with this code...

`.ui-dialog {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}`

...which is based on the fact that the z-index of `.ui-widget-overlay` is `9998`.

Additionally, to fix the problem where the overlay does not cover the full height of your page (as `.ui-widget-overlay` only has a height of `1000%`), I came up with this:

`.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}`

Comment: Both overrides worked for me across browsers - thanks ban-geoengineering.

Answer (score 6):

You need to stop using appendTo like this and use the new dialog option "appendTo"

like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" });
```

Taken from jquery-ui documentation 
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 4):

All I need was `z-index:1` applied to `ui-dialog`. There was no `z-index` I could apply to `ui-widget-overlay` to make this work.

I'm doing this in Wordpress including the 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-dialog' scripts. Here's my relevant css:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {    
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #aaaaaa;
    opacity: 0.3;  
}    

.ui-dialog {    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;    
    overflow: hidden;   
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you create a jsFiddle to recreate this issue outside your environment?  If not, here are some ideas off the top of my head:

Put your javascript inside of a document ready block, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Your javascript here...
});
```

Change btnOpendialog to be a non-ASP.NET server control.  Since all it does is open the jquery dialog, it has no need to be a server control.  Change it to this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnOpendialog" value="Button" />
```

Comment: $(function () { is same as $(document).ready Clear .. it wouldn't make a difference to change the button anyhow I need asp.net buttons. Thanks for your help. I fixed it already.